# build parent child category breadcrumb from multidimentional php array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-3

help me to build a dynamic function to display any number of sub categories. As of now there are only three level of category. please guide me to build a code to process any number of sub categories for a single parent and to display it as breadcrumb format.

Below is codeigniter index function getting all categories from categories table

```
public function index() {
    $dbdata['table'] = 'categories';
    $dbdata['select'] = array('id', 'parent', 'name');
    $dbdata['where'] = array('type' => 'post');
    $records = $this->ot->get_records($dbdata);
    $category = array();
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        if ($record['parent']) {
            $parent = $this->get_parent($record['parent'], $records);
            if ($parent['parent']) {
                $super_parent = $this->get_parent($parent, $records);
                $category[] = $super_parent['name'] . ' > ' . $parent['name'] . ' > ' . $record['name'];
            } else {
                $category[] = $parent['name'] . ' > ' . $record['name'];
            }
        } else {
            $category[] = $record['name'];
        }
    }
    echo '
<pre>';
    print_r($records);
    echo '<hr>';
    print_r($category);
    echo '</pre>';
}

protected function get_parent($parent, $records) {
    $key = array_search($parent, array_column($records, 'id'));
    return $records[$key];
}
```

Obtained Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => Category 1
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [parent] => 1
        [name] => Category 2
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [parent] => 2
        [name] => Category 3
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => Category 4
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [parent] => 4
        [name] => Category 5
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 6
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => Category 6
    )
    [6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => Category 7
    )
    [7] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => Category 8
    )
    [8] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => Category 9
    )
    [9] => Array
    (
        [id] => 10
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => Category 10
    )
    [10] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => Category 11
    )
    [11] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12
        [parent] => 0
        [name] => Category 12
    )
)
Array
(
    [0] => Category 1
    [1] => Category 1 > Category 2
    [2] => Category 1 > Category 2 > Category 3
    [3] => Category 4
    [4] => Category 4 > Category 5
    [5] => Category 6
    [6] => Category 7
    [7] => Category 8
    [8] => Category 9
    [9] => Category 10
    [10] => Category 11
    [11] => Category 12
)
```

Comment: "kindly provide the php code .." sorry no, this is not a free coding service, if you write your own, even it it does not work, we will try and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
public function index() {
            $dbdata['table'] = 'categories';
            $dbdata['select'] = array('id', 'parent', 'name');
            $dbdata['where'] = array('type' => 'post');
            $records = $this->ot->get_records($dbdata);

            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($records); $i++) {
                $records[$i]['category'] = $this->category($records, 0, $records[$i]);
            }
        }

        function category($records, $parent = 0, $record = NULL) {
            if ($record) {
                $parent = '';
                if ($record['parent']) {
                    $parent = $this->category($records, $record['parent']);
                }
                return $parent . $record['name'];
            } else {
                $super_parent = '';
                $key = array_search($parent, array_column($records, 'id'));
                if ($records[$key]['parent']) {
                    $super_parent = $this->category($records, $records[$key]['parent']);
                }
                $super_parent .= $records[$key]['name'] . ' / ';
                return $super_parent;
            }
        }
```